# Adobe Animate CC with CreateJS movieclip timeline

Tags: javascript, adobe, createjs

im working a project with Adobe animate CC. I have created a movieclip into mainline stage and inside of that movieclip there is some frames which i want them  to be executed when i click on my listener as far as i have done that but nothing happens.
[This is movieclips's timeline that i want to play/execute](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a0Bkq.jpg)

```
this.flashup.addEventListener("click", fl_ClickToGoToAndPlayFromFrame_3.bind(this));

function fl_ClickToGoToAndPlayFromFrame_3()
{
    this.gotoAndPlay("up");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The keyword 'this' that you have in your function is referencing the function and not your MovieClip.

One way that you can achieve what you're after is to add  an event argument as a parameter in your function.  This parameter represents your 'click' event. You will also need a reference to the current target (the flashup MovieClip) inside your function.

For example:

```
this.flashup.addEventListener("click", fl_ClickToGoToAndPlayFromFrame_3.bind(this));

function fl_ClickToGoToAndPlayFromFrame_3(event)
{
    event.currentTarget.gotoAndPlay("up");
}
```